# Latest Selenium exceptions became too verbose. How to stop it?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I have an application that uses Selenium and Firefox. 
Up until now I have used Selenium 2.53.1 and Firefox 46.0 and it was relatively ok. 
I tried to upgrade to:
Selenium 3.0.1 and Firefox 49.0.1. The driver itself seems to work, but I have many issues with the logging produced by selenium and the geckodriver.

The major issue is that I used to collect exceptions and output them using 
e.getMessage() or e.toString(), but now it outputs a huge string like this:

```
 Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, firefoxOptions={args=[], profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAK...
```

that can be even up to 10M. This can easily fill up the disk space when running for awhile.

Is there any way to control what will be printed?

Comment: The easiest way of fixing this would basically be to tweak what you log. I am not sure if you really want to be doing a e.toString(). Why not skip using that ?

Comment: thanks. The e.toString() contains a lot of info that is needed for debugging in case of failures. eventually that what I did, outputting only a substring of it.